# how can i make this function return null?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ return a “NULL” object if search result not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639255/c-return-a-null-object-if-search-result-not-found)

I'm trying to return NULL on a certain condition but it won't let me, why not and how can i make it return a null value or 0?

```
struct Entity
{
    USHORT X;
    USHORT Y;
    UINT Serial;
    USHORT SpriteID;
    EntityType Type;
    Direction FacingDirection;
};
```

the function is:

```
Entity& GetEntityAt(int index)
                {
                    if (!GameObjects.empty())
                    {
                        lock_guard<mutex> lock(PadLock);
                        Entity& result = GameObjects[index];
                        return result;
                    }
                    return NULL; // <- this won't compile
                }
```

Comment: NULL isn't a reference...

Comment: what do you mean? sorry i'm new

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371094/returning-a-null-reference-in-c

Comment: Change `Entity&` to `Entity*` and other according changes if you want to return NULL.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a null reference in C++.  Your choices include:

- change your function to return a (smart) pointer.
- create a dummy sentinel object (`const Entity null_entity`), and return a reference to that.

Comment: What about `boost::optional`? :o

Comment: @chris: I'm not familiar with that.  But that's why I hedged my bets and said "your choices include..." ;)

Comment: Or throw an exception. Depends what the calling code expects.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I see, that part sounded a bit limiting to me. Anyway, `boost::optional` is like a nullable type. Either it's valid and has a value, or it's invalid. Though maybe more expressive, it allows for some of the same syntax as a smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

References can't be NULL. You have to use pointers instead:

```
Entity* GetEntityAt(int index)
                {
                    if (!GameObjects.empty())
                    {
                        lock_guard<mutex> lock(PadLock);
                        return &GameObjects[index];
                    }
                    return NULL;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

A reference *IS* the object it references.  Since NULL is not an object, you cannot return NULL if the function returns an reference.