# Why does it NOT seg fault on dereference? unique_ptr

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

I would expect the following code to segmentation fault before it gets inside the method and print anything. Why doesn't it? How come the execution can go inside the method and print output for example?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void method(int x){
            std::cout << "wut" << std::endl;
            m_list.push_back(x);
        }
    private:
        std::vector<int> m_list;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> example;
    example->method(0);
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is just that -- undefined. Anything can happen when your program causes undefined behavior -- including seemingly sane behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This code appears to achieve the return of a null reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894891/this-code-appears-to-achieve-the-return-of-a-null-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, of course, undefined behavior, as others have pointed out.

However, in many C++ implementations, this will indeed not crash until after the output, because the `NULL` pointer is never actually dereferenced before then.

Your `main` essentially boils down to `reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(nullptr)->method(0)`. Since `method` is a non-`virtual` method of `class Foo`, that translates to `Foo::method(0)` (with `this` set to `nullptr`).

The output line does not reference `this` at all, so it's only when `m_list` is accessed that `this` is first dereferenced (and consequently crashes).

If `method` had been `virtual`, the call to it most likely would have crashed, as in typical implementations, calls to `virtual` methods do dereference `this`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it required an instance to reference to get to get there but apparently not and it makes a bit more sense seeing your rephrasing of the call. It wasn't a shock to me that it seg faulted inside. I guess my c++ is rusty. I thought for sure the non-smart pointer would be different but it behaves in the same undefined way.